# Touched property of mat-select-country always getting false even after touched

Tags: javascript, angular, select, mat, country

Not able to show validation errors for mat-select-country since  "form.get('country').touched" always returns false.

```
  <mat-select-country label="" placeHolder="" formControlName="country" 
                  [trimInput]="true"> </mat-select-country> 
  <mat-error>{{form.get('country').errors.required &&
               form.get('country').touched ? 
                'This field is requied':''}}
  </mat-error>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Comment: 1. check the developer tools for errors in the console. 2 check if you have imported the ReactiveFormsModule. 3. check if you have your form control under a formGroup directive in the template

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.